# SQL Server: multiple SELECTs in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am an SQL newby and I'm struggling with the following (simplified) Query.

It must extract an Account number from a master file (Master) and the associated transactions from a Current table (nTrans) and a History table (nTransArc) using the common Account number fields. This works fine.

The part I can't get to work is it also needs to extract Vat transactions from the VatTrans (Current) and VatTransArc (History) tables using a link between the TranCode in the nTrans/nTransArc tables and the VTranCode in the VatTrans/VatTransArc tables. This is the code in red between the lines (and the later INNER JOIN).

Can anyone help?

```
SELECT Mast.MAccNo,
    Tran.TAccNo,Tran.TranCode,
    Vat.VTranCode,Vat.TaxCode
FROM (SELECT AccNo,TranCode FROM nTrans 
    UNION ALL SELECT AccNo,TranCode FROM nTransArc)
'-------------------------------------------------------'
FROM (SELECT VTranCode,TaxCode FROM VatTrans 
    UNION ALL SELECT VTranCode,TaxCode FROM VatTransArc)
'-------------------------------------------------------'
Tran JOIN Master Mast ON Tran.TAccNo = Mast.MAccNo 
    INNER JOIN Vat ON Vat.VTranCode = Tran.TranCode
ORDER BY Mast.MAccNo
```

Comment: You can combine multiple result sets together using UNION (which will put one on top of the other) or by JOIN (which will combine the sets side by side).  What should the final resultset be like?

Comment: They need to be side by side, hence the INNER JOIN, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax to make this work. I tried every variation I can think of in SQL Management Studio, but they all come up with errors (and  very cryptic error messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my best guess:

```
SELECT 
    m.MAccNo,
    t.TranCode,
    v.TaxCode,
    vt.taxcode
FROM 
    Master m inner JOIN
    (SELECT 
        AccNo,TranCode 
    FROM 
        nTrans 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        AccNo,TranCode 
    FROM 
        nTransArc) t ON 
    m.MAccNo = t.TAccNo   INNER JOIN 
    (select
        TaxCode,
        VTranCode
    from
        Vat 
    union all
    SELECT 
        TaxCode,
        VTranCode        
    FROM 
        VatTrans 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        TaxCode,
        VTranCode 
    FROM 
        VatTransArc) v ON 
    v.VTranCode = t.TranCode
ORDER BY 
    m.MAccNo
```

Comment: Thank you, Beth. That worked perfectly. I tried to vote you up, but it tells me that a "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"? I don't know how to build the reputation. Sorry.

Comment: welcome to SO, to understand reputation points, check out [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question I believe the following will get you what you want:

```
SELECT m.MAccNo
    , t.TAccNo
    , t.TranCode
    , v.VTranCode
    , v.TaxCode
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN nTrans t ON t.TAccNo = m.MAccNo 
INNER JOIN VatTrans v ON v.VTranCode = t.TranCode

UNION ALL 

SELECT m.MAccNo
    , t.TAccNo
    , t.TranCode
    , v.VTranCode
    , v.TaxCode
FROM Master m
INNER JOIN nTransArc t ON t.TAccNo = m.MAccNo 
INNER JOIN VatTransArc v ON v.VTranCode = t.TranCode

ORDER BY m.MAccNo
```

This gets all your current data in one query and then gets all your historical data in the second query and then combines the results.

Comment: Thank you, Becuzz - I tried that format and it also works perfectly. Clicking the Vote Up button tells me that a "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"? I don't know how to build the reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version sql you're using but this is a bit more readable. Also, if you do this sort of `union all` frequently with your archive tables, you should consider adding a view.

```
; WITH Trans AS (
    SELECT AccNo,TranCode
    FROM nTrans 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AccNo,TranCode
    FROM nTransArc
), WITH Vats AS (
    SELECT TaxCode,VTranCode
    FROM Vat 
    union all
    SELECT TaxCode,VTranCode        
    FROM VatTrans 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TaxCode,VTranCode 
    FROM VatTransArc
)

SELECT 
    m.MAccNo,
    t.TranCode,
    v.TaxCode,
    vt.taxcode
FROM Master m 
INNER JOIN Trans t 
    ON m.MAccNo = t.TAccNo
INNER JOIN Vats v ON 
    v.VTranCode = t.TranCode
ORDER BY m.MAccNo
```